# Php sorting doesn't seem to work for me

Tags: php, sorting

I have an anchor tag in my table header and it calls a controller method. I used this,

```
<th width="15%" align="center" class="grid_header">Category
  <?=anchor('customer/basic/'.$keyword.'/Category/'.$this->customerlist->
 fieldTest('dbCategory', $sort_field, $sort_order), 'Category')?></th>
```

and i have this method,

```
 function Basic($keyword = $this->input->post('keyword'),$sort_field = 'default_field',$sort_order = 'default_order')
    {
        //Using form input to determine what fields to search in the table with $keyword

        $section = $this->input->post('section');
        //Start prepping the query
        foreach($section as $key => $tbl_field) 
        {
            //For first field generate 'like' statement, the rest get 'or_like'
            if($key == 0) {$this->db->like($tbl_field, $keyword); }
            if($key > 0) { $this->db->or_like($tbl_field, $keyword); }
        }
        //Perform the query, and set the results as an array
        $query = $this->db->get('tbl_customer');
        $result = $query->result_array;
        //Sort the Array
        $result = $this->customerlist->orderBy($result, $sort_field, $sort_order);
        $data['customerdata'] = (object)$result;  //I like to work with objects in my views
        print_r($data['customerdata']);
        //Load the view with the sorted search results
        $data['keyword']=$keyword;        //
        $data['sort_field']=$sort_field;  // send these to the view for sorting links
        $data['sort_order']=$sort_order;   //
        $this->load->view('customerdetails', $data);
   }
```

I get the error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE` in the line

```
function Basic($keyword = $this->input->post('keyword'),$sort_field = 
                    'default_field',$sort_order = 'default_order')
```

Any suggestion...

**EDIT:**
Source: http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/112696/#571876

Answer (score 1):

The default value in your parameters cannot be a variable.

Comment: You still have `function Basic($keyword = $this->input->post('keyword') ...` the parse error is saying that the default value (`$this->input->post('keyword')`) isn't valid. The default value has to be a *constant* (ie. not start with a $)